# Using the Echo Command with Sleep command

Tags: shell, scheduling, sleep

So I asked a question on here a few weeks ago and the response I got was helpful but I figured I would add some info to get a better response.

I work with a computer system that has 8 servers (4 primary 4 alternates) and has 16 nodes on those servers (4 on each server with the same on each alternate).  The nodes can't load until the servers come online.  So I have been writing 2 lines of codes that are separate until I can figure out how to connect them together.

```
for i in `echo server1; echo server2; echo server 3; echo server4; echo server5; echo server6; echo server7; echo server8`; do
echo $i
/remcmd $i username password 'superuser /reboot'
echo
done
```

Then my second command would be

```
for i in `echo node1; echo node2; echo node3; echo node4; echo node5; echo node6; echo node7; echo node8; echo node9; echo node10; echo node11; echo node12; echo node13; echo node14; echo node15; echo node16
/remcmd $i username password 'superuser /reboot'
```

Is there a way to reboot the servers then wait for 9 minutes then to reboot the nodes.  I have tried piping but did some research and it doesn't like it.

Any help anyone could give, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your `echo`s are superfluous. If your naming conventions are sane (i.e. no whitespace), you can say `for i in node1 node2 node3; do something; done`

Comment: What is a "node" in your parlance? A virtual machine and the servers are the hosts? A software service? It sounds like you expect your nodes to survive the underlying server being rebooted, or else you'd not reboot them manually.

Comment: The nodes are computers for people to use.  They boot off the information from the servers.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) to schedule a command in the future ([`man at` for usage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at)).
Either on your server or on the nodes depending on what they are and which would be better suited to control the reboot.

```sh
servers="server1 server2 server3 server4"
nodes="node1 node2 node3 node4"
remcmd="something"

for server in $servers; do
  echo "server [$server]"

  for node in $nodes; do
    echo "node [$node]"

    # Locally schedule a node reboot in 9 minutes
    at now + 9 minutes <<< "$remcmd $node username password 'superuser /reboot'"

    # or remotely schedule the node reboot
    $remcmd $node username password 'at now + 9 minutes <<< "superuser /reboot"'
  done    

  # Reboot server now
  $remcmd $server username password 'superuser /reboot'
done
```

Comment: I'd also note that it sounds like you are doing something strange and you might have an XY problem, [asking the solution to the wrong question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/260677).

Comment: Thanks I will try this when I get a chance again.  I appreciate it